# Channel adminTelegram bot stops getting the updates after another admin sends a post to the channel

Tags: c#, console-application, telegram, telegram-bot

My telegram bot which is programmed in C# using NetTelegramBotApi library, is one of the three admins of my channel and when I run the bot, it just works well until another admin(human-admin not bot-admin) sends a post to the channel.

> **The bot stops getting the updates and answering them after human-admin posts to the channel.**

This a piece of code that sends the post to my channel:

```
if(update.Message.Chat.Username == "xxxx" || update.Message.Chat.Username == "yyyy")
{
var req = new SendMessage(ChID, text) { ParseMode = SendMessage.ParseModeEnum.HTML, DisableWebPagePreview = true };
await bot.MakeRequestAsync(req);
var req2 = new SendMessage(update.Message.Chat.Id, "✅Your post was sent successfully.✅");
await bot.MakeRequestAsync(req2);
continue;
}
```

For more information ChID is the chat ID for my bot and the channel and my bot checks whether the bot-user is one of the human-admins or not. And if the user is a channel admin the bot sends the post to the channel.

Please help me fix this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem exactly in your getting updates code.

**Firstly** as you know bots can't recieve messages from another bots, so this is cause why bot-admin's post well done.
And **secondly** you should be definetly sure that all types of updates are handled when it gets them. Frequently scenario with such problem is incorrect checking for update types.

In your case should check any [update](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#update) for **channel_post** or **edited_channel_post** types because now it skipped in your code and bot throws an exception when gets update with those types of update object.

Also note, that need catch exceptions in all cases if you want your bot not to be dropped.

Comment: @Naser.Sadeghi Can I contact U? please get me your mail. thnks

Comment: @HosseinGanjyar What's the problem? Can I help?

Comment: @Naser.Sadeghi
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45256430/telegram-telesharp-massive-requests-discuss-about-flood-prevention-limit?noredirect=1#comment77476661_45256430