# Telegram (Telesharp) - Massive requests (discuss about flood prevention limit)

Tags: c#, telegram

(I'm using [TLSharp](https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp) for connect to Telegram Service)

I want search 400,000 channels, so call service ***SearchUserAsync*** for 400,000 times. I call this service every 15 seconds, but I get flood prevention for 1 day (~70000 seconds).

***What's best way for Call telegram services for n times?***

Comment: Well, the service has a request limit. Just stop requesting before reaching that limit

Comment: @SirRufo How I understood that when reaching that limit?

Comment: The limits should be documented or ask Telegram about that limits. Telegram has implemented that limits so they are the only valid partner to ask about it. Then implement in your software not to go beyond that limits.

Comment: @HosseinGanjyar Which method do you use? get updates or webhook?

Comment: @Naser.Sadeghi no method, I using service **SearchUserAsync **